# install npm and package at root level of a web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am building a web app using node.js. I have a `client` folder which contains all the front-end codes, and a `server` folder which contains all the back-end codes. Is it ok to run npm install on the `server` folder. In that case, all the node modules and `package.json` files will be in the server folder? Or is it better to install them at the root folder level outside of the `server` folder?

Comment: you should bundle up your application.

Comment: Is the frontend static html/css/js? Or does it use node_modules/FE framework (e.g. react)?

Comment: What is your main concern?

Comment: @DanielA.White what you mean by bundle up?

Comment: @JBallin frontend is react

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add more context your question, such as how you run the app locally, how you plan to deploy, a link to the code etc.

Answer (score 0):

As you spearated the `client` and `server`, I guess your client and server are in microservice architecture which they are should be independent.
Both client and server will define their own packages to being used, no reason to have the `package.json` in the root folder.
I believe you can just maintain each of the package.json under client and server.

However, if you are in MVC(backend will render your frontend), you will locate the `package.json` at root folder.

Comment: my front-end is react, does it work without being the root folder?